# Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. in react js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I already provide different key .Why it is giving me warning ?
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/0xvqw6159n

```
<TableBody>
              {fetchData.map(([title, row], index) => {
                return (
                  <Fragment>
                    <TableRow key={index}>
                      <TableCell colSpan="2">{title}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    {row.map(({ displaytext, value }, i) => (
                      <TableRow key={index + i}>
                        <TableCell>{displaytext}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{value}</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                  </Fragment>
                );
              })}
            </TableBody>
```

Comment: `index + i` does not guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: You have duplicates. When index is 0 you create 0 + 0, 0 + 1, 0 + N and then index goes to 1 and you have 1 + 0 and so on...

Comment: please suggest better way

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/0xvqw6159n I added one but still  same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index + i` isn't unique for every value of `index` and `i`.

Let's say `fetchData` and `row` are both of length 2, so `index` and `i` will both count from 0 to 1.

```
key = index + i

index  i     key
0      0     0
0      1     1
1      0     1
1      1     2
```

This produces 1 twice, so the keys aren't unique. Converting to string would help:

```
key = String( index ) + String( i )

index  i     key
0      0     "00"
0      1     "01"
1      0     "10"
1      1     "11"
```

Or you can multiply by `row.length` to produce unique integers.

```
key = ( index * row.length ) + i

index  i     key
0      0     0
0      1     1
1      0     2
1      1     3
```

Answer (score 21):

First of all, you are setting the `key` at wrong line. `Fragment` does not render into HTML, however it requires the `key` prop.

```
<Fragment key={index}>
   <TableRow>
```

Secondly, I would suggest you to add an unique id to your nested properties, since `index + i` does not guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Are your `title` or `display text` unique? If so, you can use them as key props.

```
<TableBody>
          {fetchData.map(([title, row], index) => {
            return (
              <Fragment>
                <TableRow key={title}>
                  <TableCell colSpan="2">{title}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                {row.map(({ displaytext, value }, i) => (
                  <TableRow key={displaytext}>
                    <TableCell>{displaytext}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{value}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
</TableBody>
```